# How do I prevent a function passed as a parameter from evaluating?

Tags: scala, anonymous-function

My `addvf` function adds the `added` parameter to a value store in a map based on the `value_name` key.

I am expecting to see the printout "You haven't made coffee yet" and the printout of

`println(values("sugar_in_coffee"))`

to be 1.

The `addvf("sugar_in_coffee")` should only be called if the `values("coffee")` is >= 1, as indicated by the `readvf` function. Instead, this addvf is being called as its declared.

If I prepend the addvf with `() =>` then the `acts("add_sugar_to_coffee")()` returns nothing.

How do I prevent the evaluation of a function passed as a parameter?

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

object dumbhash {

 val actions = new HashMap[String, ()=>Unit]

 def e(action_name: String) = {
   actions(action_name)()
 }

  val values = new HashMap[String, Int]
    values += "coffee" -> 0
    values += "bread" -> 0
    values += "sugar_in_coffee" -> 0
    println(values("coffee"))

def readf(value_name: String, sufficient:Int, t:()=>Unit, f:() => Unit): ()=>Unit = {
    if (values(value_name) >= sufficient) t else f
}

def addvf(value_name: String, added:Int, f:() =>Unit): ()=>Unit = {
   val v = values(value_name)
   values(value_name) = v + added
   f
}

val acts = new HashMap[String, ()=> Unit]

def desc(str: String) {
  println(str)
}


values("coffee") = 0
values("sugar_in_coffee") = 1
values += "made_coffee" -> 0

acts += "check_coffee" -> readf("coffee", 1,
        readf("sugar_in_coffee", 1, () => desc("The coffee smells brown, like you spilled too much sugar in the cup."),
        () => desc("Strong as love black coffee, waking you into this morning." )),

         readf("made_coffee", 1, () => desc("You drained the cup."), () => desc("You're the type who needs coffee to make coffee")))

acts("check_coffee")()

acts += "add_sugar_to_coffee" -> readf("made_coffee", 1, addvf("sugar_in_coffee", 8, () => desc("You dump sugar into the raspberry tree coffee mug.")),
 () => desc("You haven't made coffee yet"))

acts("add_sugar_to_coffee")()
println(values("sugar_in_coffee")) //returns 9!


}
```

Comment: This is super confusing -- can you distill this down to the simplest example that creates the behavior you don't want?

Answer (score 0):

Try to define addvf as

```
def addvf(value_name: String, added:Int, f:() =>Unit): ()=>Unit = () => {
   val v = values(value_name)
   values(value_name) = v + added
   f()
}
```

Btw, what you really need here is a state monad) see [http://eed3si9n.com](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/State.html) for reference)